# Rails - How to have two user id's associated with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I am using devise as my auth framework.  I have a report model which belongs_to :user and a user model which has_many :reports.  When I set/same the report status to "closed" I want to save the current user as the user who "closed" the report, which could be other than the user who created the report.  So I added another column to the report modem called closed_by_user_id:integer:index.  I wasn't sure how I could accomplish this with the standard model user associations.  So I added some code to save the current_user to the record when "Closing" a report.  This then shows up in the table.  I then want to display both the user who created the report (which it does automatically using the the magic devise helpers) and I want to display the user who "closed" the report.  This doesn't work automatically, or at least I don't know how to go about it.  So I tried calling a find method on the user model using the current user at time of closing/save a report on the index view iteration over the reports.  I get back an ActiveRecord Relation and a value of true.  A query in the rails console I do get back the correct record but a puts u.name outputs "User".  Not sure where to go from here.  Any ideas from those who've played with this more complex scenario before?  I would very much appreciate an education regarding this.  Thank you

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,     :timeoutable

  has_many :reports
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

2.2.1 :011 >   u = User.where(id: 2)
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 2, name: "Test User", username: "tuser", email: "testuser@mail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$BuPxu4JKZeVSK2AR6DaNT.KthntX0lb3SmAFq5I5mID...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2015-03-30 19:04:10", last_sign_in_at: "2015-03-30 19:04:10", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2015-03-30 19:04:09", updated_at: "2015-03-30 19:04:10">]>

2.2.1 :012 > u.name
 => "User" 
2.2.1 :013 >
```

Answer (score 0):

On the reports, have a `closed` column with a boolean set to false by default, and a `closed_by` column in your reports table, which is an integer.

From the show view, have a 'close' button which submits a form. The closed form would have hidden fields eg.

```
f.hidden_field :closed_by, val: current_user.id
f.hidden_field :closed, val: true
```

This could then run an action in the controller to update the reports attributes, eg.

`update(report_params)`

Now the closed boolean is set to true, you could call the user ID by finding the ID of the user who's ID ended up in that column. In the reports controller, you would find the user and assign it to an instance variable.

```
@closer = User.find(params[:closed_by])
```

This will check the closed_by column retrieve the integer, then look up the user by the ID.

Now, in your show view, you can call the user attributes. So for example if your user had a name, you could call:

```
<%= @closer.name %>
```

You could also use the boolean in the view to display your 'closed' text. eg:

```
<% if report.closed == true %>
    <p>Report Closed</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply!  Let me digest this a bit.  I do already have a column in the reports table which gets set to "Closed" (:status).  And a column closed_by_user_id which does get set when closed.  But perhaps your method is cleaner.  I thought about the look up in the controller too, but I'm trying to list the closer on the index action where I would show a number of reports.

Comment: Because the user that closed the post may not own it, this can become a bit tricky. You could do it by running the `find_by(params[:closed_by])` method inside of the loop, but if you have many on a page it could result in many uneccessary searches being made. So you could wrap it in an if statement to only retrieve this information on the ones that have been closed. `if status == closed`

Comment: I think I was on this same track, but that's where I get a return value of true i n the view and "User" in the console.

Comment: abbott567 - I took a different route, perhaps not the cleanest. Instead of jumping through a lot of hoops, I added a helper to the reports view passing the report.closed_by_user_id. In the helper method I do a look up of the User model for the user. I've got will_paginate on the index view so the queries are minimal. Your interest is most appreciated!! Like you said, it's a tricky one. I didn't want to make it harder than it had to be